# Input 0 of layer conv1 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: [None, 256, 3]

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network

First of all, I know that the NN is expercing an array. This one seems to be unrelated.

What I have is a U-Net, a rather standard one. In the code (below) I tried both generator and passing data as arrays. Both approaches complain about data shape being wrong (see post title). But I am passing a (None, 256, 256, 3) arrays!
I would appreciate if you point me to where the error is. Most likely something stupid and simple :)
The code is a Colab notebook, it is supposed to be executed from top to bottom, error produced by the last line ("test" function) with the real broblem being in Keras:fit()

Code:
I have images (identical for now) in source and labels folders.

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount("/content/drive/", force_remount=True)

#!pip install -q efficientnet 
#import efficientnet.tfkeras as efn

#!pip install livelossplot
#from livelossplot.tf_keras import PlotLossesCallback

import numpy as np
#from sklearn.utils import shuffle

from glob import glob
from pathlib import Path
from shutil import copyfile

import pandas as pd

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

#from tensorflow.keras.utils import Sequence

import sys
import random
#import math
#import numpy as np
#
#import skimage.io
#from skimage.util import img_as_ubyte
#from skimage.util import random_noise
#from skimage.transform import rescale
#from skimage.color import rgb2gray
#from skimage.transform import rotate
#import skimage.filters
#from scipy import ndimage
#
#import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#import matplotlib.patheffects as PathEffects
#
import os
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
#
#import json
#import datetime
##import skimage.draw
#
#import pickle
#
#from copy import copy, deepcopy
#
#import tensorflow as tf
#import tensorflow.keras.layers as Layers
from tensorflow.keras import regularizers
#
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adamax
#
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import array_to_img, img_to_array
#
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
#
from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16,preprocess_input
from tensorflow.keras.applications import InceptionResNetV2, Xception, NASNetLarge
#
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE
#
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Dense, Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Lambda, concatenate, BatchNormalization, GlobalAveragePooling2D, UpSampling2D
#from tensorflow.keras.layers import LeakyReLU
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import LambdaCallback
#from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ReduceLROnPlateau, LearningRateScheduler
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
#
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
#from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
#
#import pylab as pl
import seaborn as sns
#
import cv2
#
##import warnings
##warnings.simplefilter("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning)
##warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
##os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'

#from tensorflow.keras.utils import Sequence
from tensorflow.python.keras.utils.data_utils import Sequence

#%tensorflow_version 1.5

# Is GPU Working?
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
tf.test.gpu_device_name()   

working_path = "/content/drive/My Drive/03_unet_selector/"

best_weights_filepath = working_path + "models/03_unet_selector_best.h5"
last_weights_filepath = working_path + "models/03_unet_selector_last.h5"

IMAGE_SIZE = 256
input_shape=(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, 3)

BATCH_SIZE = 8
EPOCHS = 20

u_model = 0

TRAINING_IMAGES_PERCENT = 0.6
VALIDATION_IMAGES_PERCENT = 0.2

nL2 = 0.2
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.0001)

def loadImage(path):
    img=cv2.imread(str(path)) #, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    img = cv2.resize(img, (IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE))
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    img = img.astype(np.float32)/255.
    img = img.reshape(input_shape)
    
    return img

arrLabeledData = []
arrExtensions = ['.jpg','.jpeg','.png', '.gif']
nCount = 0

for strExtension in arrExtensions:
  for strImagePath in Path(working_path + "images/inputs/").glob("**/*" + strExtension):
      # Get the input image
      strImageName = os.path.basename(strImagePath)

      # Get corresponding output image (label)
      strLabelPath = working_path + "images/labels/" + strImageName
      
      # --- 
      img_src = loadImage(strImagePath)
      img_lbl = loadImage(strLabelPath)

      arrLabeledData.append(
          {
              "src" : strImageName,
              "X" : img_src,
              "Y" : img_lbl
          }
      )
      
      # ---
      
      if(nCount % 10 == 0):
        print(nCount)
      nCount = nCount + 1

nImageIdx = random.randint(0, len(arrLabeledData) - 1)

img_src = loadImage(join(working_path, "images/inputs/", arrLabeledData[nImageIdx]['src']))
img_lbl = loadImage(join(working_path, "images/labels/", arrLabeledData[nImageIdx]['src']))
#img = img.reshape((IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE))
print(arrLabeledData[nImageIdx]['src'])
plt.imshow(img_src) #, cmap='gray')
plt.show()
plt.imshow(img_lbl)
plt.show()

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
  samplewise_center=True,
  rotation_range=0,
  width_shift_range=0,
  height_shift_range=0,
  zoom_range=0
)

def deleteSavedNet(best_weights_filepath):
    if(os.path.isfile(best_weights_filepath)):
        os.remove(best_weights_filepath)
        print("deleteSavedNet():File removed")
    else:
        print("deleteSavedNet():No file to remove")  

def plotHistory(history, strParam1, strParam2):
    plt.plot(history.history[strParam1], label=strParam1)
    plt.plot(history.history[strParam2], label=strParam2)
    #plt.title('strParam1')
    #plt.ylabel('Y')
    #plt.xlabel('Epoch')
    plt.legend(loc="best")
    plt.show()
    
def plotFullHistory(history):
    arrHistory = []
    for i,his in enumerate(history.history):
        arrHistory.append(his)
    plotHistory(history, arrHistory[0], arrHistory[2])    
    plotHistory(history, arrHistory[1], arrHistory[3])  

def createModel(nL2=0.2, optimizer="adam"):
  inputs = keras.Input(shape=(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, 3))

  conv1 = layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal', name="conv1")(inputs)
  conv1 = layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal', name="conv1a")(conv1)
  pool1 = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), name="pool1")(conv1)
  conv2 = layers.Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal', name="conv2")(pool1)
  conv2 = layers.Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal', name="conv2a")(conv2)
  pool2 = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), name="pool2")(conv2)
  conv3 = layers.Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal', name="conv3")(pool2)
  conv3 = layers.Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal', name="conv3a")(conv3)
  pool3 = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), name="pool3")(conv3)
  conv4 = layers.Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal', name="conv4")(pool3)
  conv4 = layers.Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal', name="conv4a")(conv4)
  drop4 = layers.Dropout(0.5, name="drop4")(conv4)
  pool4 = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), name="pool4")(drop4)

  conv5 = layers.Conv2D(1024, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal', name="conv5")(pool4)
  conv5 = layers.Conv2D(1024, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal', name="conv5a")(conv5)
  drop5 = layers.Dropout(0.5, name="drop5")(conv5)

  up6 = layers.Conv2D(512, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal', name="up6")(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(drop5))
  merge6 = layers.concatenate([drop4,up6], axis = 3)
  conv6 = layers.Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal', name="conv6")(merge6)
  conv6 = layers.Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal', name="conv6a")(conv6)

  up7 = layers.Conv2D(256, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal', name="up7")(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2), name="up7a")(conv6))
  merge7 = layers.concatenate([conv3,up7], axis = 3)
  conv7 = layers.Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal', name="conv7")(merge7)
  conv7 = layers.Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal', name="conv7a")(conv7)

  up8 = layers.Conv2D(128, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal', name="up8")(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2), name="up8a")(conv7))
  merge8 = layers.concatenate([conv2,up8], axis = 3)
  conv8 = layers.Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal', name="conv8")(merge8)
  conv8 = layers.Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal', name="conv8a")(conv8)

  up9 = layers.Conv2D(64, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal', name="up9")(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2), name="up9a")(conv8))
  merge9 = layers.concatenate([conv1,up9], axis = 3)
  conv9 = layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal', name="conv9")(merge9)
  conv9 = layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal', name="conv9a")(conv9)
  conv9 = layers.Conv2D(3, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal', name="conv10")(conv9)
  conv10 = layers.Conv2D(1, 1, activation = 'sigmoid')(conv9)

  model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=conv10)

  model.compile(optimizer = optimizer, loss = keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(), metrics = ['accuracy'])
    
  #model.summary()

  return model

def gen(bIsTrain):
  while True:
    arrBatchImages = []
    arrBatchLabels = []

    for i in range(BATCH_SIZE):
      transform_parameters = {
        'theta': random.randint(0, 180),
        'flip_horizontal': random.randint(0, 1),
        'flip_vertical': random.randint(0, 1)
      }

      if(bIsTrain):
        nStart = 0
        nEnd = int(len(arrLabeledData) * TRAINING_IMAGES_PERCENT - 1)
      else:
        nStart = int(len(arrLabeledData) * TRAINING_IMAGES_PERCENT)
        nEnd = nStart + int((TRAINING_IMAGES_PERCENT + VALIDATION_IMAGES_PERCENT) - 1)

      nImageIdx = random.randint(nStart, nEnd)
      img_src = arrLabeledData[nImageIdx]['X']
      arrImgSrc = img_to_array(img_src)
      arrImgSrc = datagen.apply_transform(arrImgSrc, transform_parameters) #/ 255.
      arrImgSrc = np.array(arrImgSrc, dtype="float32")

      img_lbl = arrLabeledData[nImageIdx]['Y']
      arrImgLbl = img_to_array(img_lbl)
      arrImgLbl = datagen.apply_transform(arrImgLbl, transform_parameters) #/ 255.
      arrImgLbl = np.array(arrImgLbl, dtype="float32")

      arrBatchImages.append(arrImgSrc)
      arrBatchLabels.append(arrImgLbl)

    yield arrBatchImages, arrBatchLabels

arrNext = next(gen(True))
#print(np.array(arrNext[0]).shape, np.array(arrNext[1]).shape)
plt.imshow(arrNext[0][0])
plt.show()

gen_train = gen(True)
gen_valid = gen(False)

def getCallbacks(monitor, mode):
    checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(best_weights_filepath, monitor=monitor, save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=True, mode=mode, verbose=1)
    save_model_at_epoch_end_callback = LambdaCallback(on_epoch_end=lambda epoch, logs: u_model.save_weights(last_weights_filepath))  
    callbacks_list = [checkpoint, save_model_at_epoch_end_callback]  # , early]

    return callbacks_list

def loadModel(bBest):
  global u_model

  if(bBest):
    path = best_weights_filepath
    strMessage = "load best model"
  else:
    path = last_weights_filepath
    strMessage = "load last model"

  if(os.path.isfile(path)):
    u_model.load_weights(path)
    print(strMessage, ": File loaded")
  else:
    print(strMessage, ": No file to load")

  return u_model

def trainNetwork(EPOCHS, nL2, optimizer, bCumulativeLearning = False):
  global u_model
  global history

  if(bCumulativeLearning == False):
    deleteSavedNet(best_weights_filepath)

  random.seed(7)
  
  u_model = createModel(nL2, optimizer)
  print("Model created")
  
  callbacks_list = getCallbacks("val_accuracy", 'max')  
      
  if(bCumulativeLearning == True):
    loadModel(u_model, False)

  nNumOfTrainSamples = int(len(arrLabeledData) * TRAINING_IMAGES_PERCENT - 1)

  STEP_SIZE_TRAIN = nNumOfTrainSamples // BATCH_SIZE
  #if(STEP_SIZE_TRAIN < 100):
  #  STEP_SIZE_TRAIN = 100

  nNumOfValidSamples = int(nNumOfTrainSamples * VALIDATION_IMAGES_PERCENT / TRAINING_IMAGES_PERCENT)
  STEP_SIZE_VALID = nNumOfValidSamples // BATCH_SIZE
  #if(STEP_SIZE_VALID < 100):
  #  STEP_SIZE_VALID = 100

  print(STEP_SIZE_TRAIN, STEP_SIZE_VALID)
  print("Available metrics: ", u_model.metrics_names)

#  history = u_model.fit(gen_train, 
#    validation_data=gen_valid, verbose=0,
#    epochs=EPOCHS, steps_per_epoch=STEP_SIZE_TRAIN, 
#    validation_steps=STEP_SIZE_VALID, callbacks=callbacks_list)
#    #workers=4, 
#    #use_multiprocessing=True)

  X_train = []
  Y_train = []
  for nIdx in range(int(len(arrLabeledData) * (TRAINING_IMAGES_PERCENT + VALIDATION_IMAGES_PERCENT))):
    X_train.append(arrLabeledData[nIdx]['X'])
    Y_train.append(arrLabeledData[nIdx]['Y'])

  #np.array(Y_train[0]).shape

  u_model.fit(X_train, Y_train, validation_split=STEP_SIZE_VALID / STEP_SIZE_TRAIN, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, epochs=EPOCHS, callbacks=callbacks_list)

  print(nL2)
  plotFullHistory(history)
  
  # TBD: here, return best model, not last one
  return u_model

def plotAllTestImages():
  for nIdx in range(10): #int(len(arrLabeledData) * (TRAINING_IMAGES_PERCENT + VALIDATION_IMAGES_PERCENT)), len(arrLabeledData)): 
    img_src = arrLabeledData[nIdx]['X']
    img_lbl = arrLabeledData[nIdx]['Y']

    arrImgSrc = img_src.reshape(1, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, 3)

    predicts = u_model.predict(arrImgSrc)
      
    img_pred = predicts.reshape(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, 3)
      
    f, axarr = plt.subplots(1,2)
    axarr[0,0].imshow(img_src)
    axarr[0,1].imshow(img_pred)
    plt.show()

def test(EPOCHS = EPOCHS, nL2 = nL2, optimizer = optimizer, bCumulativeLearning = False):
  global u_model
  
  u_model = trainNetwork(EPOCHS, nL2, optimizer, bCumulativeLearning)
  print("loading best model")
  u_model = loadModel(u_model, True)

  plotAllTestImages()

  print(">>> done <<<")

np.random.seed(7)
test(EPOCHS, nL2, opt, False) # **Error is displayed here**
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue is using append to create X_train and Y_train.

I would check the shapes of those and try using stack instead, which will add a dimension at the beginning for the number of samples. Here's a simplified example:

```
a=np.array([[0,1,2],[3,4,5]])
b=np.array([[6,7,8],[9,10,11]])
c=np.stack((a,b))   #shape (2,2,3) with the first 2 representing the number of samples
```

Comment: Cannot figure out how to stack data when I increase sizes of X and Y arrays. What changes should be made to the part where append was used?

Comment: Shape of a resulting (when using append) arrays is as expected: (126, 256, 256, 3), 126 is num. of images

Comment: Strange- if arrLabeledData[nIdx]['X'] is an array, it seems that X_train would be a list of arrays rather than a single array. If this is the case, you can do np.stack(X_train) to turn the list of 3D arrays into a 4D array.
If not, I'm not sure where the problem is.

Comment: To the comment of Jennie: I think this is not the issue. The dimension of arrays I pass to "fit" is (126, 256, 256, 3), 126 is num. of images. AFAIK, this is what we should pass - fitst is the num. of items, then 3 numbers for the image dimensions. 

I am still looking for suggestions: please help.

Comment: Additional info. When data feed is implemented via Sequence, everything works.

Comment: Could you please help me to understand: I have data with the following shape: (NumOfImages, 256, 256, 3)
Now if I call np.stack(X_train) as you are suggesting, what shape should I expect?
In other words, my experience with Python is far from exellent, and I am trying to understand how have you arrived to your suggestion.
Thank you.

Comment: I pointed that out because the X_train=[ ] part seemed to create a list of 3D arrays (a list with 126 elements, each of which is a (256, 256, 3) array). Stack would combine them into a single 4D array that would be (126, 256, 256, 3). But it seems that this is what you have already, especially if sequential works.  

I tried running some of this but it's very long with a lot of preprocessing. I think it may be helpful if you simplify the code so that it uses images like MNIST images with minimal preprocessing, or creates mock arrays, and then either post here or as a new question.